# Multiline values in Subversions autoproperties possible?

Tags: svn, automatic-properties

Is it possible to create a property in the autoprops section of .subversion/config file which contains multiline values?

So that it would look like:

```
svn pg myprop
```

will output

```
1st line of prop
2nd line of prop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [it doesn't appear so](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.confarea.html).

In fact it's not even possible to include ";" in a autoprop value, though that's [expected to change with Subversion 1.7](http://code.google.com/p/svnbook/issues/detail?id=36):

---

The semi-colon problem is irritating for `svn:mime-type` properties:

```
*.html = svn:mime-type=text/html;charset=utf-8
```

Whoops.

---

Sometimes formats like `.subversion/config` provide some kind of line continuation:

```
foo = blah blah blah
  blah blah
  blah blah

or 

foo = blah blah blah \
blah blah blah \
blah blah
```

But, Subversion itself doesn't seem to follow such conventions. They wouldn't help you anyway, since *this* ability to break lines just makes it possible to span one logical line across multiple physical lines. The value of the `foo` property will not contain any line breaks once the file has been parsed.